# AWK read-ahead pattern capture

Tags: bash, awk

I am re-editing for clarity -- Thanks to everyone for their input.

I'm doing some scripted file processing with awk and trying to capture the value of the timestamp, then retroactively apply it to the log --

Example log --

```
20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database wan
20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127202240
20191127:20:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127:20:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127:20:22:42 023116-[INFO]:-Backup completed successfully
20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database tew
20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127212240
20191127:21:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127:21:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127:22:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database tree
20191127:22:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127:22:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127:22:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127222240
20191127:22:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127:22:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127:22:22:42 023116-[INFO]:-Backup completed successfully
```

There may be several runs in a single file -- I cannot use the date/time, because there is a chance that the directory creation could push off the backup timestamp.

To further complicate the pattern, the backup will always encounter a cleanup, but may not always be successful.

I was trying to use awk to perform this --

If I use:

```
awk '/Timestamp/{ f=$5 }{ if ( f!="" ) print f,$0 }
```

Then not only do I miss the first 3 lines, but I would end up tagging the first 3 lines of the next job with the wrong stamp.

I thought I might be able to use getline, but it consumes the lines -- and it's not quite right due to the processing order...

The desired output is to tag all the job lines with the Timestamp

```
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database wan
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127202240
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:42 023116-[INFO]:-Backup completed successfully
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database tew
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127212240
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database tree
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127222240
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Beginning cleanup
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:42 023116-[DEBUG]:-Cleanup complete
20191127222240 20191127:22:22:42 023116-[INFO]:-Backup completed successfully
```

I am assuming that the easiest method is to buffer the lines and then retroactively apply the timestamp --

Something akin to --

```
{
  if ($0 ~ /Backup Timestamp/) { 
    timestamp = $NF; for (i=0; i<nb; i++) { 
      print timestamp,backup[i] 
     }; 
     nb=0; 
  }
  if (timestamp == "") { 
    backup[nb++] = $0 
  }
  else { 
    print timestamp,$0 
  }
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about your ultimate goal. Are you saying you need to find the `Timestamp` line and then make sure the backup Timestamp is the same as the time for the log entries up to that point and then output all entries up to that point with that timestamp? Can you show a few lines of your expected output and point out how it differs from the original?

Comment: With which line exactly does one job start and end? The line `Starting backup of database tew` is beginning of the job and `Backup completed successfully` is the end? What do you want to do with it?

Comment: [edit] your question to clarify your requirements and provide the expected output given the input you posted. Is there always a line with just `...` in it immediately after every Timestamp line? If not get rid of them and make sure the sample input you provide in your question truly looks like your actual data. Using getline would almost certainly be the wrong approach, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: I updated the question with some better examples and expected output.
Ty for your follow up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your question amounts to how many lines can precede your TimeStamp, and is storing that number of lines in awk ok?   You can store the lines with something like:

```
{
        if ($0 ~ /TimeStamp/) {
                f = $5;
                for (i=0; i < nb; i++) {
                        print f,backup[i]
                }
                nb=0;
        }
        if (f == "") {
                backup[nb++] = $0
        } else {
                print f,$0
        }
}
```

Comment: This does accomplish the task by also storing as an array -- 
Thank you very much for your answer - it's always good to see multiple solutions to the same problem.

Comment: If you included expected output, etc., in your question you'd probably have seen even more solutions, maybe even some better ones, idk.

Answer (score 2):

The way I understand is that you want to timestamp the lines which represent a successful backup. According to your statements, these appear in 4 consecutive lines and the last line contains the time-stamp.

The way to do this is to keep track of the last 4 records in an array using the modulus operator `(%)`. This looks like this:

```
awk '{a[FNR%4] = $0}' logfile
```

In the above, we actually do nothing, except keep track of the last 4 lines. Now we can add an extra pattern-action pair to perform the expected result:

```
awk '{a[FNR%4] = $0}
     /Backup Timestamp/{
        tstamp=$NF
        for(i=1;i<=4;++i) print tstamp,a[(FNR+i)%4]
     }' logfile
```

which creates the output"

```
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database wan
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127202240 20191127:20:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127202240
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database tew
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Creating backup directories
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[DEBUG]:-Getting database size
20191127212240 20191127:21:22:40 023116-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20191127212240
```

Comment: This is perfectly functional and concise. Ty.
I can see that in a scenario where the forward pattern was variable, the hardcoded `4` could be replaced with a variable based on NR/FNR.

Comment: I actually need to include all the lines for the job, but this gave me the info I needed.